# Email notifcations based on specific dates i.e. employee anniversarries

Tags: views, 7, rules

We are utilizing Drupal 7 as an intranet application for our company. One of the content types of the app is a Views-based Employee Directory. Within this directory is a field detailing the employee's start of employment date.

My boss requests a feature implemented where we will receive notifications via e-mail in regards to upcoming anniversaries of employee start date, i.e. 1 year, 5 years, 10 years, etc.

Is this something I can create using Rules+Views? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to configure a rule that will run with cron. Then it will check the employee start date field as the condition and send an email as the action.